# Передача данных из одной формы в другю

Tags: php, post

Задача такая: посетитель заполняет форму (имя и телефон) и данные отправляются методом post после чего его перенаправляет на другую страницу, где ему нужно нажать или не нажать на кнопку. При нажатии на кнопку - эти данные тоже перенаправляются методом post. И вот как записать эти данные во вторую форму которую отправляет посетитель (имя и телефон, например)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [сессии](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php). В PHP есть супер-глобальный массив $_SESSION. Можно туда все что нужно записывать. (ниже пример из документации)

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();

echo 'Добро пожаловать на страницу 1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();

// Работает, если сессионная cookie принята
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';

// Или можно передать идентификатор сессии, если нужно
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
?>
```

После просмотра `page1.php`, вторая страница page2.php чудесным образом получит все данные сессии.

```
<?php
// page2.php

session_start();

echo 'Добро пожаловать на страницу 2<br />';

echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
echo $_SESSION['animal'];   // cat
echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

// Можете тут использовать идентификатор сессии, как в page1.php
echo '<br /><a href="page1.php">page 1</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Да это именно то что нужно.

Comment: Да это именно то что нужно. А вот удивительно но факт - вот так отображается на сервере http://fr79630j.bget.ru/index.php

Comment: @АлександрЧерноусов если вы скопировали код как есть, то он у вас не правильно отображается, там должно было выйти еще два поля